# Прототипы в объектах JS

Tags: prototype, javascript, объекты

У меня есть глобальный объект (назовем его Foo). Я хочу сделать одно из его свойств так же объектом, но на прототипах (свойство bar).
Делаю так:

```
Foo = {
    bar: {
        constructor: function(value) {
            this.value = value;
        },

        constructor.prototype.foobar: function() {}
    }
}
```

Но, ясное дело, тут есть ошибка. Проблема в том, что во всяких учебниках не разбирают такие случаи, да и в интернете тоже не нашел информации. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так что-ли ?

```
var Foo = {
    a: 1,
    bar: (function () {
        var bar = function () {}; //конструктор
        bar.prototype.a = 0; //свойство a
        bar.prototype.b = 0; //свойство b
        bar.prototype.sum = function () { //метод sum
            return this.a + this.b;
        };
        return bar;
    })()
};
var test=new Foo.bar();
test.a=1;
test.b=4;
console.log(test.sum()); //5
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/CK7nv/

а скажите, зачем оно вам надо ?

Comment: Спасибо.
У меня имеется один большой объект, который предоставляет широкий набор функций. Одна из этих функций - всплывающие окошки, которые написаны с использованием прототипов. Вот и появилась проблема вставки этих окошек в объект, т.к. я их изначально писал независимо.